# Runing UIautomatorViewer with AVD

Tags: android-virtual-device, uiautomatorviewer

I would like to use Googles UIautomatorViewer to analyse a third Party App running in a Android Virtual Device.
So far, I found a lot of toturials for the UIautomatorViewer using a real device and the ADB.
But is there a way to use a emulated device?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can analyse emulator easily with uiautomatorviewer.
let me explain steps.

1) create emulated device from android studio and give it name ex. demo

2) Open cmd from emulator folder by typing "cmd" in search bar.

You will find folder here = "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator"

3) Hit command " emulator @demo " it will open your emulated device called demo.

4) Now open uiautomatorviewer

Start analyse whatever you want on your device.